# JavaScript code not run when clicking submit button in Wordpress admin page form

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I have created an `HTML` form in the admin pages of a `Wordpress` installation. When I press the submit button I want the inserted data to be validated using a `JavaScript` function so that `alert`s are displayed when the data is not correctly inserted. I have tried all the things I have come across, but I have not been able to make it work. It should be something small, but I am not able to see it at this point.

The only thing I do is to `echo` out an `HTML` form to be shown using `PHP` and include some `JavaScript` function to be run. What is wrong in the code below? The `{$this->form}` part is just a string variable containing the `HTML` form. This works as expected.

```
public function __toString()
{
    return "
        <script>
        function validateForm()
        {
            alert(\"FOOOOO\");
            return false;
        }
        </script>
        <h1>Heading</h1><br>
        <form method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"return validateForm()\">
            {$this->form}<br>
            <input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Submit me!\" /><br>             
        </form>
    ";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case, the error turned out to be naming the JavaScript function `validateForm()`, as this is an internal function in the Wordpress core. Changing it to `validate_form()` or whatever fixes the issue.